# Chrome workspace FTP upload

Tags: google-chrome, ftp, google-chrome-devtools

Can the Google Chrome dev tools be used to directly change the files on the server for example by directly interacting with an ftp server? It would make PHP editing much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DevTools can update any files that are editable via Sources, including PHP and HTML. CSS is only updated directly via the elements panel. Other text file types can be updated through the Sources panel where you map the files.

DevTools directly has no knowledge of FTP/SFTP/FUSE mounts/etc. All it knows is local filesystem structures. So, if you use some software to mount a remote filesystem locally as a new folder or drive, then you can map it to DevTools just fine. I have done this myself in the past and have seen others do this setup as well. You simply need to research your OS and see what software is available that you are comfortable with to handle the mounting.

Warning though, with large project file structures this can make things slow.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately editing DOM elements doesn't update PHP or HTML mapped local files. This is currently a limitation of the workspace feature. CSS Styles only.

As for server mapping, it should be possible but Chrome seems to be crashing when I try adding a mapped FTP location. I haven't had a chance to test any other computers of versions of Chrome/Windows

Currently using Chrome 43.0.2357.130 on Windows 10 Insider Preview 10130

Comment: One and a half year later and I find myself in the same situation. Chrome crashes whenever a mounted directory mapped. Additional info: When Chrome asks for access permission to that directory, it only shows a dot (.). Did you ever found a solution?